# What is going wrong with this SSIS derived Expression

Tags: ssis, conditional-statements

```
((DT_STR,20,1252)OccuranceRegion == "US" && ((DT_STR,20,1252)LegalEntity == "AECB" || (DT_STR,20,1252)LegalEntity == "FSB" || (DT_STR,20,1252)LegalEntity == "Both")) 
? DATEADD("day",30,CapCreationDt) : (ISNULL(MaxofRevSCIAndSCI) ? (DT_DATE)"1900-01-01" : MaxofRevSCIAndSCI)
```

Whenever I put conditions as

```
OccuranceRegion == "US" AND 
LegalEntity is null
```

The result is coming as NULL, I have also checked the value for MaxofRevSCIAndSCI, its not null. Why, it is not going in else part?

Comment: MySQL or MS SQL Server? Plese don't tag products not involved.

Comment: I apologies. Will take care from this time only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any function of NULL (except the specialised, "NULL-killing" functions ISNULL and the like) evaluates to NULL.  You only compare LegalEntity to string constants.  These expressions will evaluate to NULL if LegalEntity is NULL.  You need to replace the NULL values in LegalEntity with something else.  Probably a derived column upstream

```
ISNULL(LegalEntity) ? "##NULL#' : LegalEntity
```

would be easier than doing this in the expression itself (because SSIS expressions are hideous to debug).

Comment: I would appreciate if you could elaborate. This condition is working fine when i pass AECB as LegalEntity. I am planning to use ReplaceNULL instead of ISNULL.

Comment: It's called "null propagation".  When LegalEntity is NULL, the result of testing it against any value will be NULL (not False, as you'd expect if it was not AECB, FSB or Both).  ReplaceNull is fine, it's the SSIS equivalent of SQL ISNULL.